# How to install yaml to site-packages

Tags: python, cmd, pip, site-packages

I want to know how to install YAML packages to site-packages because I need it for Blender. I already tried `"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\bin\python.exe" -m pip install yaml -t"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\python\lib\site-packages"` as administrator, but this appeared. [image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the package is PyYAML so you need to install it via

```
pip install PyYAML
```

NOTE: Be aware that while the name of the package on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) and the name of the python module are almost always the same, they do not have to be. In this case, the package is called PyYAML, however once you've installed it, it's imported via

```
import yaml
```